# Simple and Easy way to get data through ajax in JSON form using laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

There is any simple method to get data from an api using ajax and data form would be JSON or HTML, I m using sximo laravel CRUD template so I want to get some data from api and want to show that data on my views using controllers function, i dont want to put my ajax code on views pages, i want to get data in controller's function, then want to send data on view and show data with laravel method.

Comment: Do you have any code yet? something working/not working? any errors?

Comment: no not yet there is no error bcoz i didnt try anything what i have to try thats what i m asking

Answer (score 0):

ajax code can be like this.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '{{ route("your.route.name") }}',
        dataType : "JSON",
        data:inputData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            // you can get all your response data here..
        }, error: function(data){
            // Error...
            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

            $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
                $("#error_"+index).html(value);
            });
        }
    });
```

you can send your data from controller like this

```
$users = json_encode(User::all());

return response()->json([
                'users' => $users
            ]);
```

here in response you can send any data to controller

Comment: you didnt get my question i have to get data from php api through ajax in json form then i have to send that json data from controller to view.